# How to handle unusual characters in tsql

Tags: t-sql, ssms

In SSMS I query for a record by ID, then copy/paste a specific value from the results grid into a new query to search for that specific value and no records are found.

The field is nvarchar & the value in question has an alpha sign, but I don't see why that should cause a problem.

[image: Screen shot form SSMS]

Comment: Stupid question - why can't you just query: select * from ['MA Data Sheet$'] where datano=825

Comment: Because I want all records with the same ChemicalForm as record 825

Comment: well, then perhaps you can do this? (just want save you from performing the manual step): select * from ['MA Data Sheet$'] where ChemicalFormHtml in (select ChemicalFormHtml from ['MA Data Sheet$'] where  datano=825)

Comment: The question was really about why I couldn't simply copy the value and enter it in another query - I thought something weird was up, some non-diplaying character or something. Adding N is exactly what I needed. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
where ChemicalFormHtml = N'...'
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I always need the N for nvarchar fields, even if they only hold ascii text?